# jQuery Autocomplete: how to refresh list?

Tags: jquery, binding, jquery-autocomplete

I have a form with a variable number of autocomplete fields that use the same select list.  These fields are added and removed as needed.  Whenever a parameter on the page is changed, I (try to) update the list for all the fields by first calling `unbind()` then `autocomplete()` with a new parameter added to the url.

```
$('input.foo').unbind().autocomplete(url?new_param=bar);
```

The problem is that unbind() does not seem to be unbinding.  When I type in the input field, it fires off the entire history of autocomplete events.

I also tried flushCache to no avail.

How do I clear out the old events?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
$(target).autocomplete("destroy");
```

Comment: This answer is the current way to do it.

Comment: It does not work for dynamically added DOM elements. This answer works: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6585109/304209

Comment: there's also $(target).autocomplete("disable"); see the api

Comment: how to check if an autocomplete is active or not, before destroying?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$ ('input.foo').unbind('.autocomplete').autocomplete ('url?new_param=bar') ;
```

Answer (score 2):

The autocomplete plugin adds a function called unautocomplete() to remove autocomplete() from fields that have it, so it should work if change your code to:

```
$('input.foo').unautocomplete().autocomplete('url?new_param=bar');
```

This unautocomplete() function should remove all of the old events.

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding Deeksy.  I tried unautocomplete, but it didn't work.  I did, however use removeData('events') and that worked!

$('input.foo').removeData('events').autocomplete('url?new_param=bar');

Note that if you do that, any other events attached to that element will get blown away.

Comment: @cinematic  Yeah, looking into the autocomplete plugin code, it's unfortunate that they namespace the 'keydown' event, but not the click, focus or other events that are added to the input as part of the autocomplete.  If they'd bothered to follow through, it would just be a matter of going .unbind('keypress.autocomplete').unbind('click.autocomplete'). etc. though that should all be in the unautocomplete() I suppose.

Comment: This solution causes items to be skipped over on down key in IE when it is reloaded.

Comment: I would answer properly with the working solution as it seems @cinematic got it working.

Comment: It seems, this function was removed since the jQuery Autocomplete plugin got a successor, the jQuery UI Autocomplete.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery provides flushCache() method (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete) to remove the contents already matched through auto-complete.

For example, if the html element used is `<input type="text" id="txtElement"/>` and auto-complete is associated with it. The flushCache can be given as follows: `$("#txtElement").flushCache();` and this would solve the problem.

Comment: Too bad this is so low in the list.  Your tip worked like a charm.  Voted up.

Comment: +1. The flushCache method works on data without clearing the settings.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using options then add cacheLength and set it to 1.  This setting will not store any of returned records.  Trust me, it has made my life better ... for all of 5 minutes.

Comment: Just to be clear in the above statement: This setting will not store any of PREVIOUSLY returned records. (Sorry!) It will perform a new retrieval of records.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you don't have a form enclosing the autocomplete input field. If you look in the code of jquery.autocomplete.js it does $(input.form).unbind(".autocomplete"); on unautocomplete(), which means the input must live inside a form tag in order to work.

Comment: $(input.form) wouldn't run. $('input.form') would select input tags with class form, like <input class="form"/>. I think what you're thinking of is $('form input'), which would be input tags inside of form tags. In any case, the code you mention above isn't present in jquery.autocomplete.js - this answer isn't applicable.