# How to remove an autocomplete once added to an element?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

After I add a autocomplete to an element like:

```
commObj=$("#communityName").autocomplete("auto_commName_backend.php",
                {'onItemSelect': handleItemSelect}, {'extraParams': 'ndo' + ndo});
```

Is there a way I could disable it or remove the autocomplete for the element dynamically?

I am using modified jquery autocomplete plugin from Dylan Verheul.
http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/autocomplete_docs.txt

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can remove the autocomplete behaviour by using following line of code:

```
if (jQuery(control).data('autocomplete')) {
  jQuery(control).autocomplete("destroy");
  jQuery(control).removeData('autocomplete');
}
```

Comment: I think that line about removeData is not needed. I tested, and after doing $(control).autocomplete('destroy') then $(control).data('autocomplete') returns undefined

Comment: With the version of jQuery UI I'm using (1.11), .data() always returns undefined. It's safer to omit the conditional and put a try/catch around the call to autocomplete("destroy").

Answer (score 11):

The easiest and safest way I found is:

```
$(control).autocomplete({source: []});
```

Alternatively, as mentioned before this also works:

```
$(control).autocomplete("destroy");
```

If you are sure your control has an autocomplete handler set.

Comment: The first option here was perfect for me.  I dynamically generate 'promotion codes', and after one has been selected, I want to remove the ability to select anything else unless the added promo was removed, so: $('#tags_promo').autocomplete('option', 'source', []); on add promo and $('#tags_promo').autocomplete('option', 'source', availablePromo); on remove.  Thanks a bunch, I tried to do all sorts of complicated stuff rather than this!

Comment: Exactly what i needed

Answer (score 4):

In the latest version of jQuery UI(1.12), `$(control).data('autocomplete')` isn't returning true even when the autocomplete data is present.

Instead, a check for the presence of `ui-autocomplete-input` class returned true.

The following should suffice, I believe.

```
if ($(control).hasClass('ui-autocomplete-input')) {
   $(control).autocomplete("destroy");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That plugin wires itself up to the `<input>` pretty tightly. If it were my page, I think I'd just have *two* tags with the same "name", one with autocomplete and one without.  When I wanted to toggle between them, I'd make one disabled and hidden, and enable/show the other. (*edit* oh and also make sure the values of the fields get copied back and forth when they switch)

Answer (score 0):

If you add a class like, say "EnableAC" to your element, you could target that class for autocomplete. When you complete the autocomplete and want to disable it, you remove that class.

Why would do you want to disable the feature though? It may confuse your users if they want to change their selection and the autocomplete doesn't fire.

Comment: I'm not sure that would work, as once the plugin is bound to the `<input>` there are going to remain in place several event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had a brief look at the js file for the plugin.

There appears to be a javascript line (number 21) during the initialisation of the jquery.autocomplete.js plugin that sets up the originating source input as:

```
input.autocompleter = me;
```

Without testing, maybe you could simply then call the following to remove the link between the plugin and the original input?

```
$('#<your input id>').autocompleter = null;
```

Comment: That *might* work, but the script also binds a bunch of event handlers.

Comment: Yeah, like I said, I've not had much of a chance to look into it as I was in a hurry but it might be a good starting point for P Coder to look into. There's no native destroy function in the plugin script that I could see.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried
$('#').autocomplete = null;
and it works.
I was allowing name change of the fly and the result wouldnt show, now it does.
The old unchanged name would show before now the new one does

Answer (score 0):

Disable autocomplete by element ID:

```
 $("#elementId").autocomplete({
  disabled: true
  });
```